# Does the Caffe machine learning framework + Nvidia DIGITS software work with Python 3?

Tags: caffe, nvidia-digits

I installed Caffe and DIGITs on python 3 and it seems to work partially, however I still get this Protobuf error about version 2.6.1 versus 3.5.

So I reinstalled `Protobuf` and was then following through with reinstalling `Caffe`. I have an Anaconda python3.6 environment and I was recompiling `Caffe` in that environment. During the `cmake ..` step, I saw that the version of python that is detected is Python2.7 instead of Python3--even though I am in the conda python 3.6 environment. Even the version of numpy detected is for 2.7.:

```
Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found suitable version "2.7.12", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found NumPy: /home/krishnab/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (found suitable version "1.11.0", minimum required is "1.7.1") 
-- NumPy ver. 1.11.0 found (include: /home/krishnab/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include)
```

So my real question is whether DIGITS works with Caffe in python 3? I could not find any clear indication in the documentation except for an opaque reference to an issue:

https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/issues/511

Can anyone clarify?